# Ошибка при одновременной обратной связи и регистрации (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Использую плагин для обратной связи Quform, при заполнении формы, помимо письма должен создаваться аккаунт для посетителя.

Письмо отправляется, а пользователь не создается. В логах такие ошибки:

> [17-Aug-2018 14:44:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to
>   be string, array given in
>   /home/h366462/site.ru/docs/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php on line 208
>   [17-Aug-2018 14:44:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to
>   be string, array given in
>   /home/h366462/site.ru/docs/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php on line 208
>   [17-Aug-2018 14:44:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/h366462/site.ru/docs/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4670

В файле class-wp-user.php это строка:

```
public static function get_data_by( $field, $value ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // 'ID' is an alias of 'id'.
    if ( 'ID' === $field ) {
        $field = 'id';
    }

    if ( 'id' == $field ) {
        // Make sure the value is numeric to avoid casting objects, for example,
        // to int 1.
        if ( ! is_numeric( $value ) )
            return false;
        $value = intval( $value );
        if ( $value < 1 )
            return false;
    } else {
        $value = trim( $value ); - это 208 строка
    }

    if ( !$value )
        return false;
```

В файле formatting.php это

```
function wp_strip_all_tags($string, $remove_breaks = false) {
$string = preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $string 
);
$string = strip_tags($string); - эта срока

if ( $remove_breaks )
    $string = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $string);

return trim( $string );
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: Вопросы к этому левому плагину

Comment: проблема скорее в хостинге. потому что связка contact form 7 и регистрация тоже не работали. а плагин довольно популярен, поэтому навряд ли дело в "левом" плагине.

Comment: Пфф.. Нормальные люди вначале проверяют стандартные фичи, а потом идут спрашивать про непонятные плаги.

Comment: какие стандартные фичи? о чем ты?

Comment: Регистрация напр

Comment: регистрация не через плагин работает

Comment: См мой первый коммент :)

Comment: это не помощь :)

Comment: Не моя вина, что ты не способен понять в чём именно помощь.